# Why does the plot of $y=x+y$ follow the y-axis?

Tags: functions, logic, graphing-functions

On online graphing calculators (e.g. Desmos, Mathway), $ y = x + y $ is a vertical line which follows the y-axis. Why does it look like this?

What term is $ x $ or $ y $ counted first?

Comment: $y=x+y$ is the same as $x=0$

Comment: The two answers and the comment that were already given are correct, but you might find it useful to do some experimenting: Try some points on the $y$-axis, say $(0,1)$ and $(0,-7)$  and some point really far away like $(0,100000000)$ and check that they all satisfy your equation $y=x+y$, so they're on the graph. Then try some points off the $y$-axis and check that they don't satisfy the equation, so they're not on the graph. Keep experimenting until it becomes obvious that the graph is exactly the $y$-axis.

Comment: $=$ means equality, not assignment. This is **math**stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

if you subtract $y$ from both sides, you get

$x = 0$

which is a vertical line with $x$-coordinate $0$,
basically the $y$ axis.

Answer (score 0):

$y=x+y$ is equivalent to
$$x=0.$$
This gives you a line parallel to the y-axis at $x=0$.

Comment: That **is** the y-axis

Answer (score 0):

If you simplify the equation by subtracting $y$ from both sides, you get the equation $x=0$. Thus, $y=x+y$ represents all of the points in the $(x,y)$ plane such that their $x$-coordinate is $0$. Thus, you get a straight, vertical line, going through the origin, because this equation's solutions are all points $(0,y)$ for $y$ a real number.